# (Swift) Linker error when trying to use parse 1.7.1 and FacebookSDK 4.0.1

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, linker, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm upgrading my iOS project to the new versions of the parse and Facebook SDKs because Swift 1.2 doesn't support older versions.

Now that I've upgraded I can't get rid of a linker error. I've added parse 1.7.1 and removed the import statement from my bridging header.
With just parse the compiler did not complain.

But since I use facebook login, I also need to include the FacebookSDK. I've added the facebookSDK 4.0.1 and this is where the problem arises.

I know have 1 warning and 9 errors. Here are the errors

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I've tried things like adding the `-ObjC` linker flag, removing and readding the SDK. Can't think of anything else.

Not sure what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I upgraded to Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2. I was importing the Facebook 4.0.1 SDK for the first time with Parse. This is what I tried so far.

1. I added the SDK libraries 
   FBSDKCoreKit.Framework, 
   FBSDKLoginKit.Framework, 
   FBSDKShareKit.Framework into your XCode Projects Framework folder. Uncheck "Copy into destination group folder" and followed the setup steps with Facebook and Parse.

and added the PFFacebookUtilsV4 library

Then I added the import to my Bridging-Headrer

import FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h

import ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h

[image: Screenshot]

I got the same error above from your question.

2. I came across a solution and deleted all the module folders in the FB SDK which was spouse to bring a solution to importing to Swift projects, and now this is my error

[image: Screenshot]

I updated the Parse SDK and still couldn't find a solution. Tried to import the libraries in the AppDelegate.swift and still couldn't do it. Tried accessing the PFFacebookUtils but after adding the FBSDK, Xcode can't find this file.

Thank you for helping..

Comment: Yup, I deleted the module folders inside the FacebookSDK too. Didn't get me to a passing build

Comment: Unfortunately no. I think there is a bug with both the new FB/Parse SDK, as nothing I tried seemed to work. Will wait for the new release with a hope it will be fixed.

Comment: The problem I was facing ended up being that the `Modules` got recreated when adding the sdk to my xcodeproj. You need to `rm -rf` all the module folders from inside the FacebookSDK after adding to get the project to stop having linker errors. Pretty substantial bug that I hope facebook gets to soon.